# RavenDB auto update date on query

Tags: database, ravendb, nosql

I'm trying to store user session on RavenDB and need to update the LastUpdatedDate date on the user object everytime that this object is selected or updated. This way, we can set the expiration bundle and if a user not enter in the website after 30 days it will expire and be deleted.

How is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A document store listener is probably the easiest way to do that. 
See: http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.0/csharp/client-api/advanced/client-side-listeners